# CCNet - Email Notification webpage url pointing to localhost?

Tags: email, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

When I send an email notification from ccnet. The webpage link in the email points to localhost rather than the ip address of the build machine.

Does anyone know how to change this?

email is as follows:

CruiseControl.NET Build Results for project ExampleProj (web page)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Project:    ExampleProj
Date of build:  2010-11-03 16:49:36
Running time:   00:00:10
Integration Request:    Administrator triggered a build (ForceBuild) from Buildbox
Modifications since last build (0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You configure it in the ccnet.config file:

```
<project>
<name>ProjectName</name>
<webURL>http://buildbox/ccnet</webURL>
```

Comment: Thanks..I had coded it there myself as localhost and forgot..my bad!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably in the XSL files under the website directory.

Comment: Lavie: any idea which file to look in? Theres many files in the directory?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that it's not, which is highly annoying.